# Excel vba Deleting a row if a cell contains a text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code:

```
Dim r As Integer   
For r = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count        
    If Cells(r, "Q") = "0" Then           
    Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
    End If
Next
```

The problem is it doesn't delete everything, it just deletes some of the rows and i have to press the button that uses this code multiple times to delete all instances of "0" in "Q"

**Answers from similar questions**

[How to reverse a For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944074/how-to-reverse-a-for-loop)
  [Delete Row based on Search Key VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614997/delete-row-based-on-search-key-vba)

Comment: That is because you are trying to delete the rows, which can change the value of rows.count. Try doing the loop in reverse.

Comment: @shahkalpesh you are correct but shouldn't you post it as an answer and show the step to process from the bottom up.

Comment: Yeah i got the idea of that it makes sense, but im not sure what do you mean by doing the loop in reverse or how to do it.

Comment: @user3249749, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944074/how-to-reverse-a-for-loop)

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Doing the loop in reverse should be straight forward (with a search on SO as well). Lets close this question as the problem at hand is solved.

Comment: @user3249749: Can you close this question please?

Comment: @user3249749 Don't use a loop - use `AutoFilter`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614997/delete-row-based-on-search-key-vba

Comment: @shahkalpesh why are you badgering the user to *close* the question?

Comment: @brettdj: Because the comment by user shows that a solution from another question has worked.

Comment: That's up to the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I appreciate this has been addressed in the comments, but for completeness, you need to reverse the order of the for/next loop as shown below:

```
Dim r As Integer   
For r = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 1 step -1
    If Cells(r, "Q") = "0" Then           
        Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
    End If
Next
```

The way you had it previously, by deleting an entire row at the start of the list, you were moving all the content up one row. By starting form the bottom up, deleting an entire row doesn't impact the rows numbers for the items you haven't processed yet.

Glad you got it sorted.